# pipeline evaluate variable in yaml file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a yaml file that contains reference to some variable that define in pipeline.

I need some way to evaluate this $ to real value after I read the yaml.

yaml file

```
chart_folder: test_chart_${my_suffix}
lint:
  enable: false
```

pipeline look like below

```
pipeline{
    agent{
        label "my_node"
    }
    stages{
        stage("test"){
            steps{
                script {
                    def my_suffix = "test"    
                    def my_yaml = readYaml file: "my_file.yaml"
                    echo my_yaml.chart_folder
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output of execution is

```
....
[Pipeline] readYaml
[Pipeline] echo
test_chart_${my_suffix}
[Pipeline] }
....
```

and I want to get the **chart_folder** as evaluated string

```
....
[Pipeline] readYaml
[Pipeline] echo
test_chart_test
[Pipeline] }
....
```

How can I do it?

Comment: That would require variable interpolation within yaml, which is not possible. You could use a template rendering engine to render the yaml, and that would interpolate the variables from your pipeline before reading in. However, that would involve extra unnecessary steps, so you should probably approach this differently.

Answer (score 1):

You can't interpolate, but you can override.

```
def my_yaml = readYaml file: 'my_file.yaml', text: "chart_folder: 'test_chart_test'"
```